# No sound notification with telegram

Tags: ubuntu-touch, notification, telegram

Since I have my Aquaris E4.5, almost 3 months, I noticed trouble with notification with telegram.
I never received sound notification, at all. Most of the time, the led is blinking  and the phone quickly vibrates, but few time the phone vibrates continuously and the only way to stop it is to push one of the three button on the right side.
Am I alone to have this trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the version update (ubuntu 14.10 (r22) -> ubuntu 15.04 (r23)) on my E4.5, this has solved the problem. I now have sound notifications, and the led is flashing green (it's flashing blue for text)

Edit : vibrating notification was hazardous, uninstall telegram and delete the two file that @PavelPerina has precised solved the problem.

Comment: For the constant vibration, they are working on it, a fix should be included in OTA-5 coming soon: https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg13897.html

Answer (score 0):

I did not experience this issue with my E4.5. The sound notification for Telegram is configured via system settings - sound - message received > choose sound.

If only vibrate on message causes this continuous behaviour, this is also the right menu to turn of vibrate on message.

I hope you can get this solved!

Comment: I have already try to change setting here, nothing changes for telegram. But as soon as I remember, I always had this problem with every version of ubuntu (now in 22). Which version are you?

Comment: Sorry, my e4.5 is broken physically, atm I use mx4 with 15.04 r2. So I'm not sure I can help you investigate the problem further...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar (not sound related) problem, what helped me was to re-install Telegram completely.

After uninstalling application, make sure to delete this folder from cache from `/home/phablet/.cache/com.ubuntu.telegram/` using file manager and also this delete this folder `/userdata/user-data/phablet/.config/com.ubuntu.telegram/` (to find this folder you have to enable *"show hidden files in File Manager"*.

Then install Telegram again using Ubuntu Store. You will be prompt to login to Telegram again as all the data has been wiped. I hope it helps with your sound issue! :-)