# Telegram notifications stopped working. Ubuntu Touch 15.04 r4

Tags: ubuntu-touch, notification, telegram

Today I noticed that Telegram Notifications do no longer appear in the notification area. In addition the dash icon no longer displays the count of unread messages.

Upon opening Telegram I was prompted to log into Ubuntu One in oder to enable notifications, be reminded later or not receive notifications. I chose log into Ubuntu One, but nothing happened except the prompt closing.

As of now there are no notifications. Telegram is allowed to push notifications under System Settings > Notifications.

Is there any way to bring the prompt back or fix this manually or is this a bug introduced with a recent update of Telegram? I don't remeber it updating though.

BQ Aquaris 5, Ubuntu 15.04 r4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the reason was a changed password to my Ubuntu One account.

The only way to be able to re-authenticate was to delete the account and then set it up again. Notifications are working again.

Keeping this Q&A for anyone bumping into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this too, but I haven't changed password at all.
Sometimes rebooting the phone is enough, sometimes uninstall and delete the file as in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643525/no-sound-notification-with-telegram/644807#644807) solved it for a while.