# How to maintain Telegram to stay logged in permanently Ubuntu Touch phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, smartphone, bq, telegram

How do make Telegram app not to log out after few hours? I have tried:

- re-install of  app (wiping local & cached folders)
- factory reset phone (wiping all data)
- deleting history of Telegram chats & deleting most of them

However the process is still repeating - after few hours I'm logged out (see screenshot). Then I need to send request, receive SMS or phone call, type in pin and telegram is running for few minutes/hours.

*Telegram app version 1.3.20.114 (issue also happen with previous version)
Phone BQ 4.5 Ubuntu 15.04 (r24)(issue also happen with previous version)*

[image: Not Authorised]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the experience. We should release the fix some time this month hopefully. We've noticed this issue affected people from China/Taiwan/Australia region, which is particularly weird. I hope the rebase on TelegramQML, which is some new glue code, will make the problem go away.

In terms of notifications, they're delivered through Ubuntu push server, but the fact that they're still coming down, and the app seems to have signed out is indeed particularly weird.

Comment: Thank you Karni. I must be glitch on Asian server as I was able to create new profile in Europe and use it on Telegram Touch App perfectly. Yet it would refuse to stay logged in when in Europe. I would have thought, it's the geographical issue - loging from one region to another, but now when back in Australia the problem stays and I'm forced to use WebTelegram. The notifications still works, but the app will log out :-( Looking forward to TelegramQML

Comment: Hi Pavel, I know I've mentioned this before, but we're very close to releasing an update. Please stay tuned!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I never experienced this, and I'm sure it's not supposed to do that (as you probably also suspect).

I fiddled around to reproduce. There are no account settings in the phone other than inside the app, so I don't think there's a problem there. (like gmail has an account in system settings - accounts) 
I opened a webapp on my pc for Telegram, and in settings - active sessions I terminated all other sessions. I thought this might be the cause of your problems. When I started Telegram on my phone, it ran and was sort of logged in, but couldn't access my chats. I could see my personal info in settings. After a reboot, I do get the exact message you show in the question. If I click OK, the dialog doesn't disappear, and I need to restart Telegram to login again. Then it works again.

Could this be causing your problem? Do you use telegram on other devices? Do you ever terminate other sessions from there? If not, this is a bug, but I wouldn't know if it's the telegram app in Ubuntu or rather telegram itself.

Comment: Then you Maarten. I have tried cancelling all other sessions, then login out of my PC Telegram - I had no active sessions and then registered again in Ubuntu Touch. The session lasted about 30sec, then logout again.
Also, in ubuntu when I'm logged out, new messages are still coming in notification - so I'm able to read it's preview in notification bar. Icons on the side also shows number of new messages, yet I'm not able to use the app as it shows not authorised!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue with Telegram after [having changed the password to my Ubuntu One account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653652/telegram-notifications-stopped-working-ubuntu-touch-15-04-r4) the other day.

Perhaps removing your ubuntu one account and then setting it up again on your phone will resolve this for you. Its more a guess than an answer though. Somebody pointed to another solution involving the manual deletion of certain files. You can find it linked in the question above.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your input. You're correct this would solve the notification issue, but this is not what my problem is. In fact my notifications are still running, while the app is logged out!